# Function that takes folder name as argument (python)

Tags: python, join, path, os.walk, listdir

I am trying to write a function that deleting all directories and files except the
one (folder_to_exclude)

```
def cleanDir(self,dirpath, folder_to_exclude, handler):     
    for root, dirs, files in walk(dirpath, topdown=True):
        for file_ in files:
            full_path = path.join(root, file_)
            if folder_to_exclude not in full_path:
                rmtree(full_path, onerror = handler)
        for folder in dirs:
            full_path = path.join(root, folder)
            if folder_to_exclude not in full_path:
                print("cleanDir  full_path  : ",full_path)
                rmtree(full_path, onerror = handler)
```

I am calling this function from another part of my code, using:

```
self.cleanDir(self.work_dir, self.script_dir, myHandler)
```

Where:

- self.work_dir: is the working directory
- self.script_dir: is the directory to exclude
- myHandler: a handler for exception (not important in my case)

**My question is:**
When I print the directories that I will delete using the line in the cleanDir function, I find that I am printing the folder_to_exclude too, and then I am deleting it.

I don't understand why !

Comment: this would be much easier to debug if you provided your output

Comment: There's no question.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, find the first point in the execution where the state of the variables is not what you expect & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe values are not the same.

You could check

```
print( folder_to_exclude not in full_path )

print( folder_to_exclude == full_path )

print( len(folder_to_exclude) == len(full_path) )
```

Maybe one of them has `spaces` or `tabs` at the end and you can't see it.

You may check if it is the same when you try to remove spaces and tabs

```
print( folder_to_exclude.strip() == folder_to_exclude )
print( full_path.strip() == full_path )

print( folder_to_exclude.strip() == full_path.strip() )
```

OR maybe you use some chars which can look similar but they have different codes.

You can use `for`-loop to compare char-by-char

```
for a, b in zip(folder_to_exclude, full_path): 
    print( a, b, a == b, ord(a), ord(b) )
```